# Add a column in an existing table and make it the primary key mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to add a column in an existing table (which has data populated) in mysql and make it the primary key?

The issue that I am running into is that the system is now generating a GUID (unique ID) for each record and ideally that should be the primary key in the table. However, the previous records will not have this GUID populated, but the new records will have this GUID populated. So the existing rows in the table will not allow me to make this GUID column the primary key.

Comment: If you don't already have a `PRIMARY KEY` column, yes, you can always add one. If you have one already and need to shift it, you'll need to show your schema.

Comment: Why not populate that field for old records to make it consistent? GUIDs can be generated easily enough.

Comment: The table does have a composite key which I want to get rid of and just make the GUID column the primary key. I can't populate the GUID myself because there is a small probability that the GUID I generated for an existing record, is in the future generated by the system for a new record, and that will cause a problem in data insertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to remove the Primary Key from your column key:

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY UIDD INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE table DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

After that you can add your new column:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD pk_column INT NOT NULL
```

Add your new IDs to the new column:

After that add the Primary Key to it:

```
ALTER TABLE table
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (pk_column)
```

You can set your Old Primary Key column to a unique index, so that queries are still fast and you have the unique constraint.

Comment: I can't use AUTO_INCREMENT. I want to populate the GUID which is generated by the system.

Comment: Edited without adding Auto Increment.

Comment: Since the old records in the table do not have the GUID column populated, I get this error: "Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'"

Comment: alter Table table add column guid varchar(100) primary key;

Comment: Use the `{}` button or four spaces of indentation to format code. Doing it as bold is inconsistent and breaks the syntax highlighting.